# Search the word, and replace the whole line containing the word in a file in Python using fileinput

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to search a particular word in a text file. For each line,where the word is present, I want to completely change the line by a new text.

I want to achieve this using `fileinput` module of python. There are two observation, I am seeing with following variations :-

**Code piece 1 :-**

```
text = "mov9 = "   # if any line contains this text, I want to modify the whole line.
new_text = "mov9 = Alice in Wonderland"
x = fileinput.input(files="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DeletedMovies.txt", inplace=1)
for line in x:
    if text in line:
        line = new_text
        print line,
x.close()
```

The above piece of code wipes out all the content of the file, and writes the `new_text` i.e. the file content is only

> mov9 = Alice in Wonderland

**Code Piece 2 :-**

```
text = "mov9 = "   # if any line contains this text, I want to modify the whole line.
new_text = "mov9 = Alice in Wonderland"
x = fileinput.input(files="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DeletedMovies.txt", inplace=1)
for line in x:
    if text in line:
        line = line.replace(text, new_text)
        print line,
x.close()
```

The above piece of code, even though adds the needed line i.e. `new_text` where `text` is found, but doesn't deletes the line, but keeps the previous data also.

That is if the line was earlier :-

```
mov9 = Fast & Furios
```

after running the above piece of code it becomes :-

```
mov9 = Alice in WonderlandFast & Furios
```

And other content of the files remain untouched, not deleted as in code in Code piece 1.

But my goal is to find the word `mov9 =`, and whatever is present along with it, I want to replace the whole line as `mov9 = Alice in Wonderland`.

How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance....

Comment: `"".join(open('file.txt'))` will transform into a single String object. You can just split it by feed line `\n` and delete the indexes you don't want.

Comment: 1 you have to write the new text and 2 it's easy to write to a new file and not have to worry about the file pointer.

Comment: @vyscond. if you wanted a string why would you not call read?

Comment: @vyscond: Of course, even with Padraic's adjustment, you're still going from "peak memory usage based on length of longest line" to "peak memory usage based on size of largest file", which is probably not a good idea if large files are a possibility. If you need a `list` of lines (with or without trailing newlines), and can't begin processing until the whole file is read, then yes, `f.read().splitlines()` (or keeping line endings, `f.read().splitlines(True)`) is fastest, but if you can avoid storing the whole file in memory, that's usually the most scalable solution.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, if you wanted to keep the line ends you would be better calling `readlines`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Actually, at least on Python 3.5, `list(f)` and `f.readlines()` are basically the same performance-wise (really should have gotten rid of `.readlines()` in Py3; it gains nothing, and leads to misuse when people don't realize files iterate by line w/o memory overhead). At least for `%timeit` tests (on a hot ~5.9 MB file with ~570K lines, using Py3.5 x64 on Linux), `f.read().splitlines(True)` actually runs meaningfully faster (takes about 2/3rd the time of `list(f)`/`f.readlines()`); higher peak memory usage (briefly stores both complete string and list at once), but faster.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: That said, I'd probably use `list(f)` if I really needed a `list` with line endings and wasn't microoptimizing; slurping and then doing `splitlines` may be fastest, but `list(f)` is short, obvious, doesn't increase peak memory usage further, and (unlike `f.readlines()`) doesn't make me cringe (because `f.readlines()` is, to me, code smell; when you see it, it's usually someone who didn't know files iterate by line already).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized that I was wrong by just an indentation. In the code piece 1 mentioned in the question, if I am bringing the 'print line,' from the scope of if i.e. if i outdent it, then this is solved...

As this line was inside the scope of `if`, hence, only this `new_text` was being written to the file, and other lines were not being written, and hence the file was left with only the `new_text`. So, the code piece should be as follow :-

```
text = "mov9 = "   # if any line contains this text, I want to modify the whole line.
new_text = "mov9 = Alice in Wonderland"
x = fileinput.input(files="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DeletedMovies.txt", inplace=1)
for line in x:
    if text in line:
        line = new_text
    print line,
x.close()
```

Also, the second solution given by [Rolf of Saxony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496769/search-the-word-and-replace-the-whole-line-containing-the-word-in-a-file-in-pyt/34497433#34497433) & the first solution by [Padraic Cunningham](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496769/search-the-word-and-replace-the-whole-line-containing-the-word-in-a-file-in-pyt/34497007#34497007) is somehow similar.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony of Saxony But how can I vote my own answer ??? If you think it's correct, then I would request you to upvote it.

Comment: Next to your answer is a greyed out tick. Click on it to accept your answer as the one that you feel best answers your question. I simply assumed that you would want to do that.

Comment: Thanks... Also, you can cast your upvote both to the question as well as my answer if you feel it is correct..

Comment: But this adds an extra new line after every line!!

Answer (score 1):

You empty you file because you only write when you find a match, you need to always write the lines:

```
import sys

text = "mov9 = "   # if any line contains this text, I want to modify the whole line.
new_text = "mov9 = Alice in Wonderland\n"

x = fileinput.input(files="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DeletedMovies.txt", inplace=1)
for line in x:
    if text in line:
        line = new_text
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

If you find a match the line will be set to `new_text`, so either `sys.stdout.write(line)` will write the original line or `new_text`. Also if you actually want to find lines starting with `text` use  `if line.startswith(text):`

You could also write to a `tempfile` and replace the original:

```
from shutil import move
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

text = "mov9 = "   # if any line contains this text, I want to modify the whole line.
new_text = "mov9 = Alice in Wonderland\n"

with open("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DeletedMovies.txt") as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w", dir=".", delete=False) as tmp:
    for line in f:
        if text in line:
            line = new_text
        tmp.write(line)


move(tmp.name, "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DeletedMovies.txt")
```

Comment: Of course, the `tempfile` approach is roughly what `fileinput` does for you (in the non-exception-raising case); `fileinput` is just moving the input file to a backup name, then opening that name and using it to replace `stdout` while working on that input file. If you're hand-implementing it, you'd probably want to have `NamedTemporaryFile` use `dir=os.path.dirname(inputfilepath)`, so you can both verify you have write permissions to the output dir, and use atomic `rename` instead of "copy-and-delete" when doing the move.

Comment: @ShadowRanger,  rename is atomic on windows?

Comment: `os.rename` is not when the target exists (and in fact, fails), though `os.replace` will succeed. If `os.replace` is available (Python 3.3 and up), then on Windows it's implemented in terms of `MoveFileEx` with the `MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING` which, if not documented as atomic officially, should be either atomic, or at worst two discrete directory table updates (which, with NTFS journaling, would appear to be atomic in the event of power loss). Either way, closer to atomic than `move` from separate partition, and becomes: Blow away target, copy data, copy metadata, delete original.

Comment: Looks like [`shutil.move` implements in terms of `os.rename` instead of `os.replace`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/shutil.py#l537) even on Python 3.5 (where `os.replace` exists), so actually, `shutil.move` will be "not even close to atomic" even for within partition `move`s on Windows (it would be closer if you explicitly deleted the target first). So for atomicity (or something close) on Windows w/Py2.7, the best you could manage is explicitly deleting the target before using either `os.rename` or `shutil.move` with a file on the same partition; on 3.3+, `os.replace` is best.

Comment: @ShadowRanger,  so there is no atomic rename using python2.7 on windows? The questions is tagged python2.7 so replace is not an option.

Comment: Yeah, you'd get "near atomic" with `os.remove(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DeletedMovies.txt")` followed by either `shutil.move` or `os.rename` with a same partition temp file though. I'd say that reducing the window in which power outages or exceptions can leave you with corrupt data from a huge window (that grows as the file in question grows) in which you can easily end up with partial data, to a tiny window (the space between two Python function calls and the associated system calls that actually perform the delete and rename as simple file table updates, with no data movement) is worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

As **vyscond** suggested:

```
import re
yourTxt = ''.join(open('file.txt').readlines())
yourTxt = re.sub(r'\bmov9\b', r'mov9 = Alice in Wonderland', yourTxt)

#Save the new text on disk
f = open('newTxt.txt', 'w')
f.write(yourTxt)
f.close()
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham All the lines must be read eventually and checked against the string "mov9". So why not doing the process in RAM? This is less computationally expensive and less tricky :)

Comment: Less computationally expensive than `open('file.txt').read()`?

Comment: Hmm I think you're right. Sorry I get back my word on "less computationally expensive". Well mine is just a way of doing it :)

Comment: If you were not replacing the original file you could also do it line by line instead of storing multiple copies in memory, I would recommend changing to .read for future readers and using a context manager

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use two file simultaneously to replace the text and write the replaced data in another file and simply delete the older file.

```
path="Hello.txt"
path2="Hello2.txt"
file1_open=open(path,"r") 
file2_open=open(path2,"w")
for line in file1_open:
if "a" in line:
print "found"
    line=line.replace('a',"replaced")
print line
    file2_open.write(line)
```

Now you can internally delete the file1_open file.
It's small and simple though may take load on CPU when with large files.

Comment: As mentioned in the question itself, I want to solve this using fileinput module.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this may not be the only solution on this theme, now that I have re-read the answers but as I knocked the code up here goes.
Keep it simple:

```
import os
text = "mov9 = "   # if any line contains this text, I want to modify the whole line.
new_text = "mov9 = Alice in Wonderland "
new=open("new.txt",'w')
with open('DeletedMovies.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if text in line:
            line = line.replace(text, new_text)
            print line
        new.write(line)
new.close()
os.rename('DeletedMovies.txt', 'DeletedMovies.txt.old')
os.rename('new.txt', 'DeletedMovies.txt')
```

It rather depends on just how big you expect this file to get.

Edit:
If you are determined to use `fileinput` despite the the fact that it will be confusing for anyone unfamiliar with that package, as it is not at all clear what is happening, then you were almost there with your existing code.
The following should work:

```
import fileinput
text = "mov9 = "   # if any line contains this text, I want to modify the whole line.
new_text = "mov9 = Alice in Wonderland "

for line in fileinput.input("DeletedMovies.txt", inplace = 1):
    if text in line:
        print line.replace(line,new_text)
    else:
        print line.strip()
```

Comment: I am aware of this method, however, I need to solve this using fileinput module.

Comment: Yes... It worked.... Thanks... However, there was a single indentation mistake in my code, which I found and posted the updated answer below.

Comment: @PabitraPati Excellent, it's always good to see the original poster of the question post a solution.

Comment: Ha ha...Thanks...@RolfofSaxony :)

Answer (score 0):

With a slight improvement to the [Rolf of Saxony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34497433/4583071) answer, this you can run the script without having to hard coded values.

```
import fileinput
import sys

filename=sys.argv[1]
old_value=sys.argv[2]
new_value=sys.argv[3]

with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        if old_value in line:
            print(line.replace(line,new_value))
        else:
            print(line.strip())
```

Now run it as `replace.py filename.txt old_value New_Value` from the command line